# This element index

Tags: javascript

I need to get the this.element index on a eventListener click. I looked for a good index solution but i didn't understand most of them.

```
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu">Link 1</li>
    <li class="menu">Link 2</li>
    <li class="menu">Link 3</li>
    <li class="menu">Link 4</li>
    <li class="menu">Link 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now i need my loop var to match my index like this

```
    var $menuItem = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');

for ( var x = 0; x < $menuItem.length; x++ ){
    $menuItem[x].addEventListener('click', function(){
        if (this.toString() + index == $menuItem[x]){
            $menuItem[x].classList.add('active')
        }
    })
}
```

I know this may not be the best way to add a link to a this element but i need the index for another function.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Only javascript

Answer (score 0):

You already have the index. The `x` variable. You can use a self-invoking function for *remembering it* in the corresponding handler:

```
for (var x = 0; x < $menuItem.length; x++) {
  (function(index) {
     $menuItem[index].addEventListener('click', function() {
       // ...
     })
  })(x)
}
```

Another option is using `Array#indexOf` function:

```
// Convert the `HTMLCollection` into a regular array!
var $menuItem = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('menu'));

for (var x = 0; x < $menuItem.length; x++) {
  $menuItem[x].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var index = $menuItem.indexOf(this);
  })
}
```

Another option is using `Array#forEach` method:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('menu'), function(el, index) {
   el.addEventListener('click', function() {
     // `index` refers to clicked element index in the collection
   })
});
```

Comment: var $menuItem = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('menu'));
var index = $menuItem.indexOf(this);

worked perfectly thank you

Comment: @Leo You are welcome! The other options should also work.